# Exposing a UDP server inside of CoreMediaIO DAL virtual camera plugin

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, xpc

I’m trying to write a [CoreMediaIO DAL](https://github.com/seanchas116/SimpleDALPlugin) plugin that will expose a virtual camera. Now, I’d like to be able to send data (frames) to this via another application. To accomplish this, I want to expose a simple UDP server. I looked at XPC services and they seem complicated. The architecture I want is:

```
Photo Booth <--> DAL plugin
                     ^
                     |
                UDP Server (listen port 12345)
                     ^
                     |
                My App (send frames to 12345)
```

Using the Networking framework and [this](https://rderik.com/blog/building-a-server-client-aplication-using-apple-s-network-framework/) tutorial as reference, I have a simple UDP server which I want to run at port 12345.

Every time my virtual camera executes, my server never launches. The error I see is following:

```
stateDidChange(to:): Server failure, error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Network.NWError error 0.)
stateDidChange(to:): POSIXErrorCode: Operation not permitted
```

Seems like a permission issue. What choices do I have to get around this? If I go the route of XPC/Mach ports, will there be a similar issue?

Thanks for your help!